# Is it possible to separately check the memory address where the variable name is stored in python?

Tags: python

```py
number = 1

print(id(number))
```

Running the above code will give you the memory address where the number 1 object is stored. But what I want to know is the memory address where the variable name number is stored. I know that the variable name and the object assigned to the variable are stored separately. Is there any way to know this?

Comment: Is there a deeper use-case to this question, or purely an exploratory / educational exercise?

Comment: @S3DEV It is a simple curiosity. At first, when I didn't know that a variable pointed to an object reference, I thought that the id() function could return the memory address of the variable name.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id): *"Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

__CPython implementation detail__: This is the address of the object in memory."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to separately check the memory address where the *variable name* is stored in python?

In short, no.

The reason is because the variable name itself is not directly assigned to a memory location. Essentially (to over simplify) - in CPython, variable names and the Python objects to which they point, are stored in a Python `dict`.

---

#### Worked example:

When you write `x = 5`, this assignment can be viewed by calling the `globals()` function, as shown here (truncated for simplicity):

```
>>> x = 5
>>> globals()

{'__name__': '__main__',
 '__doc__': 'Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment',
 '__package__': None,
 ...,
 'In': ['', 'x = 5', 'globals()'],
 'Out': {},
 ...,
 'x': 5,                   # <-- Here
 '_i2': 'globals()'}
```

As you can see, it's just a Python `dict` which holds the variable names, in the current namespace, and (a representation of) their value.

Per the `globals()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

> Return the dictionary implementing the current module namespace. For code within functions, this is set when the function is defined and remains the same regardless of where the function is called.

#### Bytecode:

In support of the statements above, if you were to examine the bytecode for `x = 5` you'd see:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the constant `5` is loaded into memory (by getting assigned to (or collected from an already existing) memory location). Then [`STORE_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_NAME) opcode is called, which if you view the [C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f2dd0a7c0b1a5112f2164dce78fcfaa0c4b39c7/Python/ceval.c#L2783) for this opcode, you'll see that `PyDict_SetItem` is called, which  adds `x` to the `LOCALS()` (in C) `dict` examined above.

---

#### C source code (CP3.12a): `STORE_NAME`

```
    TARGET(STORE_NAME) {
        PyObject *name = GETITEM(names, oparg);
        PyObject *v = POP();
        PyObject *ns = LOCALS();
        int err;
        if (ns == NULL) {
            _PyErr_Format(tstate, PyExc_SystemError,
                          "no locals found when storing %R", name);
            Py_DECREF(v);
            goto error;
        }
        if (PyDict_CheckExact(ns))
            err = PyDict_SetItem(ns, name, v);    // <-- here
        else
            err = PyObject_SetItem(ns, name, v);  // <-- or here
        Py_DECREF(v);
        if (err != 0)
            goto error;
        DISPATCH();
    }
```

[Direct GitHub link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f2dd0a7c0b1a5112f2164dce78fcfaa0c4b39c7/Python/ceval.c#L2783)